# Add Custom Taxonomy into Script

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, scripts

I am trying to add a script for an affiliate widget into the back end of my website so I can use a custom taxonomy for the variable.

Basically below where the script asks for destination I would like to add the name of the current destination. Destination is a custom taxonomy on my wordpress site.

```
<script async defer src="//widget.getyourguide.com/v2/core.js" 
onload="GYG.Widget(document.getElementById('gyg-widget- 
5b2dae9ec139c4.60431654'),{'currency':'USD','localeCode':'en- 
US','numberOfItems':'3','partnerId':'XXXXXX','q':'DESTINATION'});"></script>
```

I have tried 
$destname = single_cat_title();
and then using 
echo ($destname) inside the script but it doesnt seem to work.

Any ideas
Richard

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use json_encode in the page that you would like to run. Here is some ideas how you to solves.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'my_taxonomy_list');
function my_taxonomy_list() {
  if (specific_page) { //check not to run in other pages
        $taxonomies = get_taxonomies(); 
        foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
            $tax_list[] = $taxonomy->slug;
        }
    ?>
    <script>
        var tax_list = <?php echo json_encode( $tax_list ) ?>;
    </script>
    <?php
  }
}
```

And then you could access tax_list to be able to use in javascript file.